# How to find databases having a certain table on a linked server (SQL Server 2012)?

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to find all databases on a linked server having the same value inside a certain table like the database on the source server which calls the query.

I've build a query which works fine as long as all databases on the linked server have this table. Otherwise it fails telling me:

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MyServer" does not
>   contain the table ""DbName"."dbo"."TableName"". The table either does
>   not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(DB SYSNAME, name varchar(255));

DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier;
SET @guid = (SELECT guid FROM TableName);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [LinkedServer].'
+ QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.tables WHERE name = ''TableName'')
INSERT #x SELECT ''' + name + ''', name
    FROM [LinkedServer].' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.TableName
    WHERE guid = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), @guid) + ''';'
FROM [LinkedServer].master.sys.databases;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT * FROM #x;
DROP TABLE #x;
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you don't know if the table exists in specific database at compile time, you have to use dynamic sql:

```
SELECT @sql += '
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [LinkedServer].' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.tables WHERE name = ''TableName'')
exec (''INSERT #x SELECT ''''' + name + ''''', name
    FROM [LinkedServer].' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.TableName
    WHERE guid = ''''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), @guid) + ''''''');'
FROM [LinkedServer].master.sys.databases;
where database_id > 4
```

so you have dynamic inside of dynamic.

Comment: What happens if the linked server doesn't have a `master` DB (i.e. isn't a SQL Server)?

Comment: This is no problem in my case - it's always a SQL Server with a master DB.

But @Ivan, did you test your solution? I tried to adapt this but I'm getting an error: "Incorrect syntax near 'TableName'."

Comment: @vso, check quotes. `print @sql` for debug.